# Show multiple times a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to show multiple times a JSX component without having to copy and paste 5 times (for example) the same component.

```
import Paciente from "./Paciente";

const ListadoPacientes = () => {
  return (
    <div className="mb:w-1/2 lg:w-3/5 md:h-screen md:overflow-scroll">
      <h2 className=' font-black text-3xl text-center'>
        Listado Pacientes
      </h2>

      <p className="text-xl mt-5 mb-10 text-center">
        Administra tus {''} 
        <span className=' text-indigo-600 font-bold'>
          Pacientes y Citas
        </span>
      </p>
      <Paciente/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ListadoPacientes
```

I tried with a simple for

`for(let i = 1; i<5 ;i++){ <Paciente/> }`

But it gave me a *Identifier expected.ts(1003)*, i'm relatively new in JSX i hope you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for loop is not working in Jsx you need to create a map of your number and return your Jsx:

```
Array(5).fill().map((_,index) => <Paciente key={index} />);
```

don't forget key in your map

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the correct one